# Filling a 2D array with a range of numbers

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I am trying to create a 2D array which is filled with the even numbers from 2 till 100 in an array with 10 rows and 5 columns.

I have created the array with these dimensions:

```
    int[ ][ ] table = new int[10][5];
```

I have also created the methods for printing the array in the required format:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ //for the rows
       for(int j=0;j<5;j++) { //for the columns 
        System.out.print(table[i][j] +k+ "\t");
      }
       System.out.println(""); 
     }       
    }
```

but printing just this gives 50 zeros in matrix/table format.

**My question is:** What method/s do I need to use to assign each number accordingly ??
 Do I need to add other methods apart from the main maethod ?

**My output should be something like so:**

```
2,4,6,8,10
12,14,16,18,20
22,24,26,28,30
```

up till 100

Comment: You missed the part that assigns values to the elements of your array. Also, you need to properly handle the insertion of commas between entries of the same row, skipping the last element.

Comment: @FDavidov my problem is just that, how do I assign each number to each element in the array

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Do you know how to assign a value to *one* element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not 100% of the syntax though):

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ //for the rows
   for(int j=0;j<5;j++) { //for the columns 

    table[i][j] = (5 * i) + j ;  // This is my addition!!!

    System.out.print(table[i][j] +k+ "\t");
  }
   System.out.println(""); 
 }       
}
```

Check this. Cannot warrant it works PERFECTLY, but this is the main idea.